# Access constructor value of another class in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, ecmascript-6

I got the following problem :

1) Two classes in class.js

```
Class1 {

   //here the constructor

   constructor(connection){

   this.connection = connection

}

  //here a class1 prop

  returnConnection(){

    return this.connection

  }
}

// class 2

Class2 extends Class1 {

  getClass1ConstructorConnection{

   return super.returnConnection();

 }
}

module.exports = {Class1, Class2}
```

Now in my route file I declare class1

```
var { Class1 } = require(./class.js);
var { Class2 } = require(./class.js);
var class1Object = new Class1({connectionObj})
```

And after that, i declare class2

```
var class2Object = new Class2();
```

if I try to console.log class2 prop like this

```
console.log(class2Object.getClass1ConstructorConnection())
```

It gets undefined.

Now, I know the best would be to declare the connectionObj as a native constructor of class 2, but for a bunch of reasons I can't, so, is there a way to inherit a constructor variable value by a parent class after its declaration in the main app workflow?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What's `connectionObj` here `new Class1({connectionObj})`?

Comment: It's a connectionObj from mysql!
And i need it as in other props of class2 i should use this connection object to do some queries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you never pass the connection to the base class. 
You have to pass your connection to the constructor

`var class2Object = new Class2({connectionObj});`